# How to convert this type of arrays into a json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I have this array:

```
[ [ '560134275538747403', 39953 ],
  [ '411510958020624384', 36164 ],
  [ '468512396948930576', 31762 ],
  [ '482286641982078977', 29434 ],
  [ '249892869127536641', 6295 ] ]
```

And I want to covert it into an object like this:

```
{
"560134275538747403":39953,
"411510958020624384":36164,
"468512396948930576":31762,
"482286641982078977":29434,
"249892869127536641":6295
}
```

Anyway to do that?
~and thx

Comment: That's an Object, not a JSON Object. There's no such thing as a JSON Object. JSON is *text*.

Comment: I'm new in this and I don't know a lot about it, sorry.

Comment: No problem, but this is a typical w3schools error. If you're using them, don't.

Comment: oh yeah, I was browsing that site :)

Comment: In the future, it's a good idea to post the code that you tried as a [mcve]. Asking "is there a way to do it", the answer is 99.9% "Yes", which you know to be the case, so you're really asking "give me the code", which is basically [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In this case, the situation is pretty trivial, so folks pretty much pop out the answer and everyone moves on, but it should be said nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr=[['560134275538747403',39953],['411510958020624384',36164],['468512396948930576',31762],['482286641982078977',29434],['249892869127536641',6295]];

const res = Object.fromEntries(arr);

console.log(res);
```

Or, as that's not widely supported, `reduce`:

```js
const arr=[['560134275538747403',39953],['411510958020624384',36164],['468512396948930576',31762],['482286641982078977',29434],['249892869127536641',6295]];

const res = arr.reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = v, a), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I got an error in the 1st one: (node:2117) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function.

Comment: Fixed @ggorlen.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead by using the ES2019 feature `Object.fromEntries(...)`,

```js
const array=[ [ '560134275538747403', 39953 ],
  [ '411510958020624384', 36164 ],
  [ '468512396948930576', 31762 ],
  [ '482286641982078977', 29434 ],
  [ '249892869127536641', 6295 ] ];

const object=Object.fromEntries(array);

console.log(object);
```

Suppose if it isn't supported in Node. Then you can use it after you install a shim of it from npm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.fromentries

Here is a Runkit link that shows it working using the shim in Node,
 https://runkit.com/embed/lkupsniraw2c

Comment: I got an error: (node:2117) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function

Comment: Ah! Since it's an ES10 feature it may not be available in your version of Node. I have updated the answer to installing a shim to make it usable. Or you can use ```reduce``` as suggested by Jack Bashford in his answer

Comment: Oh, so that's why.

Comment: @Dj-Gamer I have included a Runkit link to show it working in Node using that shim mentioned in my answer. Hopefully, the ES10 features ship out soon :)